# Linq OrderBy in select if count is over 0

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a query that looks like this:

```
var qContactsOpen = from x in promo.Contacts
   where x.type == type && (x.closure_id == 0 || x.closure_id == null)
   orderby x.id descending
   select new ContactsGrid
   {
      Id = x.id,
      DescriptionA = x.description_A,
      Address = x.address,
      PostalCode = x.postal_code,
      Vat = x.vat_iva,
      CategoryDescription = x.Categories.description,
      SpecializationDescription = x.Specializations.description,
      AreaDescription = x.Areas.description,
      Location = x.location,
      Subject = x.subject,
      Note = x.ContactsActivities.OrderByDescending(o=>o.date).FirstOrDefault().note
   };
```

The last field in the select, is a string property, and I need that if `x.ContactsActivities` is greater than 0, take the result or else take string empty.

If I run this, returns an error that it cannot orderby null.

Comment: What do you mean by "over 0"? Non-empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds you might just want:

```
Note = x.ContactsActivities
        .OrderByDescending(o => o.date)
        .Select(o => o.note)
        .FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
```

By putting the projection earlier, it means you end up with the null result from `FirstOrDefault` as the final result, rather than then trying to dereference the result to get at a note from a null reference.

The null-coalescing operator will then turn a `null` value into the empty string. Note that means you'll get an empty string even if there *was* a result, if its `note` property happened to have a null value.